# Will this "off delay" circuit work if a continuous trigger is applied to pin 2?

Tags: timer, 555

This is an off delay circuit using a 555 timer. I want to know if this can be used even if the trigger signal is continuous. If, not what modification is needed?

[image]

Comment: `Looking at the interior circuit of the 555, if the TRIGGER input is held low for longer than pulse length, it will keep the lower comparator CB high and the OUTPUT will remain high.` From https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/180721/238590

Comment: "*If the trigger input is still less than 1/3 Vs at the end of the time period the output will remain high until the trigger is greater than 1/3 Vs. This situation can occur if the input signal is from an on-off switch or sensor.*" From https://electronicsclub.info/555monostable.htm#edgetrigger

Comment: Identical diagram from this post https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/324207/238590   "*when the trigger was held low for longer than the configured output pulse width, the output would stay high.*"

Comment: "*I want to know if this can be used even if the trigger signal is continuous*". When the trigger is held continuously `low`, what behaviour do you want for your 555 circuit ? Should it remain high or or go back to low ?

Comment: Please edit your question and add a timing diagram of the behaviour you want.

Comment: what modification i need to do so that if trigger low continue then also the out put should give a pulse only .