# Triggering the 555 timer for a short period

Tags: capacitor, 555

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fs2G8O.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This is the mechanism which was used in a 555 timer used in the mono-stable mode, it was designed so that even if the switch is closed for an extended period of time it is only momentarily triggered .
I was not able to figure out how exactly it works, and it does since I tried making a physical prototype of the same.
Also I was not able to find this type of trigger mechanism, can anybody let me know what it is called?

Comment: Show the full schematic. Where is the threshold pin connected?

Comment: I have added the full schematic in the output just triggers a MOSFET didn't think it would be important to add that in.

Comment: It's a form of differentiator.

Comment: Hint: The C1 capacitor is the difference maker. If you know how capacitor works, then you can see the map clearly. If not show what you come up with, we can help you

Comment: Falstad’s web sim has a 555 one shot timer . Use that

Comment: [Related 1](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/324207/why-does-this-edge-trigger-work-on-input-of-555-monostable-config). [Related 2](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/180721/238590)